# Importing a PhoneGap project in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I'm having great difficulties importing a PhoneGap project in Android Studio.
I have tried many different ways I found on many websites but none of them seems to work.

For example, I've created a new project using Cordova in command line like this:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "hello_world"

$ cd hello

$ cordova platform add android
```

(I have tried using phoneGap commands instead of cordova, didnt work either)

Then in Android Studio, I go in file->import project and I've tried to select the "hello" directory as well as the "platform/android" one.
none of them worked, Android Studio tells me that this project isn't a graddle-based project

Other problems I've ran into using different methods found on the web :

- The project 'hello' is not a Gradle-based project
- Error running android module not found
- Error: package org.apache.cordova does not exist

So if anybody can tell me a good method for doing this or redirect me to a good (and working :) ) site that explain how to do it, I would really appreciate

Additionnal info :

- Android Studio 1.1.0
- Cordova 4.3.0
- My Sdk/tools and Sdk/build-tools in my `PATH` as well as a `JAVA_HOME` variable

Answer (score 1):

here is the procedure:
after **import project**, select your folder for the `hello` project your created and then follow through all the default options.(remember to select **Gradle**)

then you will see the run button grayed out. what you have to do is go to **edit configuration** and then add a new android application, under **general** tab, select module as **android** and launch `com.example.hello` for activity. Then you can click **ok**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Android Studio was sitting there, complaining about the project not being "Gradle-enabled".

Solution: Updating Cordova to the latest version 5.4.1 (and in the process npm, etc.) solved the problem here.

On the first 'cordova build android' cordova downloaded the gradle .zip-file. After that I was able to 'import' the project into Android Studio just like all the tutorials tell you to.

Edit: After updating Cordova you may have to...

"cordova platform remove android"

and then

"cordova platform add android"

Edit^2: I'm using the latest Version of Android Studio (1.5.1). That may make a difference too...

Answer (score -1):

Just import the project directly in Android Studio (File -> Import) and it will tell you that it is not a Gradle-based project, and you should get something like this:

[image]

After you click next, it will generate all the necessary Gradle files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I import the project in Android Studio it tells me that it is not a Gradle-based project but it doesnt show me this window.
Instead it tells me this : The project 'hello' is not a Gradle-based project More Information about migrating to Gradle
and it redirect me to this page http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/intellij_to_gradle

Comment: I'm doing the same. Checking all the boxes on this screen. It gives a huge message of all the CordovaLib files that weren't copied over. I do not see my MainActivity.java file. It generated numerous error when building.